# Sample Azure Mobile app for Xamarin.Forms

Tags: android, azure, mobile, xamarin.forms

I'm new to Azure and playing with Mobile App. I've created correctly all infrastructure stuff through Azure portal, downloaded backend service and frontend Xamarin.forms sample (through Mobile App -> Quick Start) and it's working (the sample code stores "TodoItem" data in SQL database and there is a nice mobile UI presented). The problem is that it's working only debug configuration. When I switch to release configuration, it simply crashes (speaking about Android version, Windows Phone/WinApp seems to be working ok in release). The weird thing is that when I check "enable developer instrumentation" for release configuration, it's working again. Any idea why is this happening, any hints what to try? Thanks a lot!

Comment: What kind of errors are you getting? What does the StackTrace say? What code is it failing on? When does it crash (when the app first launches or after a button is clicked, etc)?

Comment: Are you using https (SSL) for connection to your API?

Comment: Hi, please what is the best way how to get the stack trace in release configuration? I was able to find some dirty way to show it through DisplayAlert, but no idea how to get it fully in text form for posting here :-( The app itself is working, but call to await this.client.SyncContext.PushAsync(); fires an exception. I have tested the sample code from Azure portal and it's not working in release as well :-( So I still guess that it must be something generic, not in code. @Adam: I've tried both, http and https, same result. Thanks a lot!